# IP over LoRa: TCP timeout

Tags: networking, tcp, latency

I am trying to tunnel IP packets via LoRa. For this I use two devices running [Meshtastic](https://meshtastic.org/).
Using ICMP I was able to determine that there is a packet loss of about 30% of the packets and a latency of about 18 seconds (not miliseconds!).

```
$ time ping 10.115.253.197 -c 20 -W 600
PING 10.115.253.197 (10.115.253.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=12612 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=15457 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=14536 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=14669 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=14803 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=17756 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=19245 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=19234 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=19280 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=19564 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=21571 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=21286 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=21525 ms
64 bytes from 10.115.253.197: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=29039 ms

--- 10.115.253.197 ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 14 received, 30% packet loss, time 19209ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12611.611/18612.706/29038.582/4040.933 ms, pipe 16

real    0m50.196s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.068s
```

I then tried running UDP over the tunnel and this worked.

```
$ ncat --verbose --wait 10m --udp 10.115.180.153 8886
Ncat: Version 7.94 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.115.180.153:8886.
Hello World!
^C
```

```
$ ncat --listen --verbose --udp --source-port 8886
Ncat: Version 7.94 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on [::]:8886
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8886
Ncat: Connection from 10.115.253.197:47920.
Hello World!
^C
```

However, when I tried to tunnel TCP, this ended in a timeout.

```
$ ncat --verbose --wait 10m 10.115.180.153 8886
Ncat: Version 7.94 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

I then made a [dump of the traffic](https://irc.mk16.de/uploads/6d860fd9216de1af/meshtastic_tcp_iperf3_over_udp.pcapng) (on the server side) and could see a lot of TCP retransmissions. Furthermore, the TCP three-way handshake does not seem to have worked.

I am now wondering which TCP parameters I need to adjust to make the tunnel work?
I ran the test on two Linux computers. The IP tunnel had an MTU of 200.

Comment: I don't think this is a good place for this question. We're more used to 10G than LoRaWan. I'd suggest perhaps electronics SE.